# программа на фиксирует новые изменение в стилях css

Tags: html, css, django

в моем проекте Django есть 5 приложений, в каждой html шаблон и стили к нему, так же есть базовый шаблон от которого наследуются другие приложения и так же наследует стили этого базового шаблона, суть проблемы в том что стили созданные раннее отлично работают но когда я например удаляю эти стили либо изменяю их на сервере не фиксируются изменения и сайт отображается со старыми стилями которых даже не существует инструменте разработчика также отображаются стили созданные ранее которых уже в коде нету и так во всех приложениях.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте пересобрать обновлённую статику вашего проекта, используя команду в вашей IDE (или консоли):
`python manage.py collectstatic`.

В браузере же выполните хард-релоад с помощью `Ctrl+F5` (перезагрузка сбросит кэш страницы и, соответственно, предыдущие файлы стилей — на их место подгрузятся обновлённые).

Comment: спасибо большое python manage.py collectstatic помогло